# Why does this Powershell loop not terminate?

Tags: powershell

This loop reads bytes from a TCP socket stream as long as `$i` is not equal `0`:

```
while(($i = $stream.Read($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length)) -ne 0)
{
    ...
}
```

I sent a `0` character to the socket and expected the loop to end. Why did it continue? I also sent `""` empty string but it still continued.

Comment: Checking for zero bytes should never be used with TCP. It is wrong ALL over the place.  This case you are using a Network Stream and often you will get to the End Of stream (overrun) and not get not get any bytes. Overrun just means you are reading data from a stream faster than receiving.  It does not mean you got to the end of the stream.  Using EOF is also wrong also in a Network stream because it means the connection is closed.  With TCP you can send multiple message over same stream without closing.  Best way is to add a byte count at beginning of message and read until you get all bytes.

Comment: As I said in my posting, null will only occur when the connection closes on opposite end.  If connection remains open(more than one message on connection) your solution will not work.

Comment: @iRon it's a NetWorkStream, OP needs to use `-gt 0` instead

Comment: @jdweng The example is from some literature. Given the example as posted, my actual question is rather "What would I need to send such that the loop terminates?"

Comment: When the connection closes the return value is null.  Inside the loop you could get one or more messages and each message needs a terminator.  It is better to use an event so you do not spend a lot or resources just looping.